# Provide POS tags as input to RNN alongwith word embedding

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have to feed input to the RNN as word embedding + POS tags. But word embedding is generated by code only. So I cannot concat embedding and POS one hot vector. What is the best way to do this task?

```py
def BidLstm(maxlen, N_TAGS, EMBEDDING_DIM, embedding_matrix):
    inp = Input(shape=(maxlen,), dtype='int32')
    x = Embedding(len(word2int) + 1,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=maxlen,
                            trainable=False)(inp)


    x = Bidirectional(LSTM(300, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25,
                           recurrent_dropout=0.25))(x)
    xa = Attention(maxlen)(x)
    xd = Dense(256, activation="relu")(xa)
    xdp = Dropout(0.25)(xd)
    xd1 = Dense(5, activation="softmax")(xdp)
    #x = TimeDistributed(Dense(N_TAGS + 1, activation='softmax'))(x)
    model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=xd1)
    return model


model = BidLstm(max(sentence_length_list),5, EMBEDDING_DIM, embedding_matrix)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
file_path = ".model.hdf5"
ckpt = ModelCheckpoint(file_path, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1,
                       save_best_only=True, mode='min')
early = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", mode="min", patience=1)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train_onehot, batch_size=32, epochs=15, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[ckpt, early])
```